# Type conversion failure in Microsoft Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I am importing a HTML file into a database in Microsoft Access and the HTML file contains a column with date.

For instance, the column contains data like "25 May 15". When I import the data into a table, I face two Import Errors.

First Error:

> It gives an Import Error called Type Conversion Failure when I import
>   the data as Date/Time. However, it works fine when I import it as text
>   format.

Second Error:

> When i add similar table which the date data is of "24 May 15", on top
>   of the current table. It gives an Import Error called Type Conversion
>   Failure. It doesn't allow me state the type of format of the date
>   column.

Need some guidance on how to solve this date/time issue.

Comment: It sounds like Gustav's solution is your only option, unless you want to write a script to remove the double quotes from your HTML before importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the date as text to a (temporary) table.

Then use a query to convert the text date to a true date with DateValue(). It will convert, say, the string "25 May 15" to the date value 2015-05-25.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Advanced" button while importing to change how Access checks the date from your source file. Set the delimiter as " " and check if your date format is correctly set to "DMY" and "4 digit year" is unchecked. Hope this solves the issue, did so for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also had the problem with csv file import. My work around invoked setting the date delimiter as a hyphen instead of forward slash. I notice this discrepancy whilst testing imports via setting the field type as text.